# R: Sort the Minimums of My Data Frame in This Order

Tags: r, sorting, minimum

I have the following data frame as follows:

```
library(future.apply)
lb <- 2:9
NBB_AR0.8 <- c(1.879, 1.065, 1.385, 1.568, 1.493, 1.732, 1.263, 0.9369)
NBB_AR0.9 <- c(0.8051, 0.7598, 1.113, 1.056, 0.9819, 0.8842, 0.679, 0.4441)
NBB_AR0.95 <- c(0.7456, 1.249, 0.8531, 1.573, 1.425, 1.181, 0.8645, 0.5171)
MBB1_AR0.8 <- c(1.806, 1.611, 1.199, 1.46, 1.253, 1.483, 1.418,1.615)
MBB1_AR0.9 <- c(0.7936, 0.7351, 0.9151, 0.9417, 0.9827, 0.9767, 0.8699, 0.9629)
MBB1_AR0.95 <- c(1.646, 1.621, 0.9941, 0.9044, 1.054, 1.247, 1.376, 1.281)
MBB2_AR0.8 <- c(1.806, 1.611, 1.199, 1.46, 1.619, 1.483, 1.498, 1.301)
MBB2_AR0.9 <- c(0.7936, 0.7351, 0.9151, 0.9417, 0.9653, 0.9767, 1.051, 0.9979)
MBB2_AR0.95 <- c(1.646, 1.621, 0.9941, 0.9044, 1.531, 1.247, 1.03, 0.9696)
MBB3_AR0.8 <- c(1.806, 1.611, 1.199, 1.46, 1.363, 1.483, 1.742, 1.161)
MBB3_AR0.9 <- c(0.7936, 0.7351, 0.9151, 0.9417, 1.025, 0.9767, 0.9018, 0.6612)
MBB3_AR0.95 <- c(1.646, 1.621, 0.9941, 0.9044, 0.861, 1.247, 1.184, 0.8825)
CBB_AR0.8 <- c(1.642, 0.9616, 1.42, 1.728, 1.326, 1.324, 1.542, 1.172)
CBB_AR0.9 <- c(0.2077, 0.2158, 0.1791, 0.1933, 0.168, 0.2211, 0.1516, 0.2133)
CBB_AR0.95 <- c(0.1039, 0.08983, 0.09176, 0.1, 0.09203, 0.08383, 0.08386, 0.08956) 
df <- data.frame(lb, NBB_AR0.8, NBB_AR0.9, NBB_AR0.95, NBB_AR0.95, MBB1_AR0.8, MBB1_AR0.9, MBB1_AR0.95, MBB2_AR0.8, MBB2_AR0.9, MBB2_AR0.95, MBB3_AR0.8, MBB3_AR0.9, MBB3_AR0.95, CBB_AR0.8, CBB_AR0.9, CBB_AR0.95)
```

- The minimum value of the vector NBB_AR0.8 is `min(NBB_AR0.8) = 0.9369`
- The minimum value of the vector NBB_AR0.9 is `min(NBB_AR0.9) = 0.4441`
- The minimum value of the vector NBB_AR0.95 is `min(NBB_AR0.95) = 0.5171`

All the three(3) above have `NBB` in common thus, they should be arranged in the row of `NBB`

- The minimum value of the vector NBB_AR0.8 is `min(NBB_AR0.8) = 0.9369`
- The minimum value of the vector MBB1_AR0.8 is `min(MBB1_AR0.8) = 1.199`
- The minimum value of the vector MBB2_AR0.8 is `min(MBB2_AR0.8) = 1.199`
- The minimum value of the vector MBB3_AR0.8 is `min(MBB3_AR0.8) = 1.161`
- The minimum value of the vector CBB_AR0.8 is `min(CBB_AR0.8) = 0.9616`

All the five(5) above have `AR0.8` in common thus, they should be arranged in the row of `AR0.8`
The others follow the same arrangement.

I wish to have the minimum values arranged as follows using `R`:

|  | AR0.8 | AR0.9 | AR0.95 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| NBB | 0.9369 | 0.4441 | 0.5171 |
| MBB1 | 1.199 | 0.7351 | 0.9044 |
| MBB2 | 1.199 | 0.7351 | 0.9044 |
| MBB3 | 1.161 | 0.6612 | 0.861 |
| CBB | 0.9616 | 0.1516 | 0.08336 |

I tried this but got this result that does not suit my expectation in arrangement:

```
    future.apply::future_apply(df[-1], 2, min)

> NBB_AR0.8    NBB_AR0.9   NBB_AR0.95 NBB_AR0.95.1   MBB1_AR0.8   MBB1_AR0.9  MBB1_AR0.95   MBB2_AR0.8   MBB2_AR0.9  MBB2_AR0.95   MBB3_AR0.8 
     0.93690      0.44410      0.51710      0.51710      1.19900      0.73510      0.90440      1.19900      0.73510      0.90440      1.16100 
  MBB3_AR0.9  MBB3_AR0.95    CBB_AR0.8    CBB_AR0.9   CBB_AR0.95 
     0.66120      0.86100      0.96160      0.15160      0.08383
```

The answers is correct but I am also interested in the arrangement.

I am also interested in this method:

```
future.apply::future_apply(df[-1], 2, which.min)
```

which gives me this:

> NBB_N10_AR0.8_RMSE    NBB_N10_AR0.9_RMSE   NBB_N10_AR0.95_RMSE NBB_N10_AR0.95_RMSE.1   MBB1_N10_AR0.8_RMSE   MBB1_N10_AR0.9_RMSE
> 8                     8                     8                     8                     3                     2
> MBB1_N10_AR0.95_RMSE   MBB2_N10_AR0.8_RMSE   MBB2_N10_AR0.9_RMSE  MBB2_N10_AR0.95_RMSE   MBB3_N10_AR0.8_RMSE   MBB3_N10_AR0.9_RMSE
> 4                     3                     2                     4                     8                     8
> MBB3_N10_AR0.95_RMSE    CBB_N10_AR0.8_RMSE    CBB_N10_AR0.9_RMSE   CBB_N10_AR0.95_RMSE
> 5                     2                     7                     6

I want it to be arranged as this table:

|  | AR0.8 | AR0.9 | AR0.95 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| NBB | 9 | 9 | 9 |
| MBB1 | 4 | 3 | 5 |
| MBB2 | 4 | 3 | 5 |
| MBB3 | 9 | 9 | 6 |
| CBB | 3 | 8 | 8 |

- The minimum value of the vector NBB_AR0.8 is `min(NBB_AR0.8) = 0.9369` under `lb = 9`
- The minimum value of the vector NBB_AR0.9 is `min(NBB_AR0.9) = 0.4441` under `lb = 9`
- The minimum value of the vector NBB_AR0.95 is `min(NBB_AR0.95) = 0.5171` under `lb = 9`

All the three(3) above have `NBB` in common thus, they should be arranged in the row of `NBB`

- The minimum value of the vector NBB_AR0.8 is `min(NBB_AR0.8) = 0.9369` under `lb = 9`
- The minimum value of the vector MBB1_AR0.8 is `min(MBB1_AR0.8) = 1.199` under `lb = 4`
- The minimum value of the vector MBB2_AR0.8 is `min(MBB2_AR0.8) = 1.199` under `lb = 4`
- The minimum value of the vector MBB3_AR0.8 is `min(MBB3_AR0.8) = 1.161` under `lb = 9`
- The minimum value of the vector CBB_AR0.8 is `min(CBB_AR0.8) = 0.9616` under `lb = 3`

All the five(5) above have `AR0.8` in common thus, they should be arranged in the row of `AR0.8`

Comment: Please help me with this as well `future.apply::future_apply(df[-1], 2, which.min)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We may use

```
lst1 <- split(setNames(out, sub(".*_", "", names(out))),  sub("_.*", "", names(out)))
do.call(rbind, lapply(lst1, function(x) x[!duplicated(x)]))
```

-ouptut

```
    AR0.8  AR0.9  AR0.95
CBB  0.9616 0.1516 0.08383
MBB1 1.1990 0.7351 0.90440
MBB2 1.1990 0.7351 0.90440
MBB3 1.1610 0.6612 0.86100
NBB  0.9369 0.4441 0.51710
```

---

```
lst2 <- split(setNames(out2, sub(".*_", "", names(out2))),  sub("_.*", "", names(out2)))
 do.call(rbind, lapply(lst2, `[`, 1:3))
     AR0.8 AR0.9 AR0.95
CBB      2     7      6
MBB1     3     2      4
MBB2     3     2      4
MBB3     8     8      5
NBB      8     8      8
```

#### data

```
out <- future.apply::future_apply(df[-1], 2, min)
out2 <- future.apply::future_apply(df[-1], 2, which.min)
```

Comment: Error: ` Error in is.factor(x) : object 'out' not found`

Comment: @DanielJames sorry, I meant `out` as the ouptut of `future_apply`

Comment: I actually have four(4) `names` like `NBB_N10_AR0.8_RMSE` instead of `NBB_AR0.8` for instance. How can I manipulate this `split(setNames(out, sub(".*_", "", names(out))),  sub("_.*", "", names(out)))` statement to fit such four(4) names such that the first two (split(NBB_N10, MBB1_N10, MBB2_N10, MBB3_N10, CBB_N10) will go for row (for they have `N10` in common) and the last two(2) (AR0.8_RMSE, AR0.9_RMSE, AR0.95_RMSE) will go for column (for they have `RMSE in common`). I used just two(2) just to be brief in my question but now need four(4) names in reality. Please help.

Comment: I never know that the number of the variable names will count.

Comment: The data frame I used is a result of simulated data such that changing the pattern will affect the outcome.

Comment: @DanielJames Do you have any other patterns

Comment: No, this is my data frame and its vector naming pattern in real life `df <- data.frame(lb, NBB_N10_AR0.8_RMSE, NBB_N10_AR0.9_RMSE, NBB_N10_AR0.95_RMSE, MBB1_N10_AR0.8_RMSE, MBB1_N10_AR0.9_RMSE, MBB1_N10_AR0.95_RMSE, MBB2_N10_AR0.8_RMSE, MBB2_N10_AR0.9_RMSE, MBB2_N10_AR0.95_RMSE, MBB3_N10_AR0.8_RMSE, MBB3_N10_AR0.9_RMSE, MBB3_N10_AR0.95_RMSE, CBB_N10_AR0.8_RMSE, CBB_N10_AR0.9_RMSE, CBB_N10_AR0.95_RMSE)`

Comment: Try `strsplit(str1, "_(?=[A-Z0-9]+\\.)", perl = TRUE)` into a list where `str1 <- c("NBB_AR0.8", "NBB_N10_AR0.8_RMSE", "NBB_N10_AR0.9_RMSE", "NBB_N10_AR0.95_RMSE", 
"MBB1_N10_AR0.8_RMSE", "MBB1_N10_AR0.9_RMSE", "MBB1_N10_AR0.95_RMSE", 
"MBB2_N10_AR0.8_RMSE", "MBB2_N10_AR0.9_RMSE", "MBB2_N10_AR0.95_RMSE", 
"MBB3_N10_AR0.8_RMSE", "MBB3_N10_AR0.9_RMSE", "MBB3_N10_AR0.95_RMSE", 
"CBB_N10_AR0.8_RMSE", "CBB_N10_AR0.9_RMSE", "CBB_N10_AR0.95_RMSE"
)`

Comment: The output of `strsplit` is a list.  You can do `m1 <- do.call(rbind, strsplit(str1, "_(?=[A-Z0-9]+\\.)", perl = TRUE));m1[,1];m1[,2]` to get the two components

Comment: I will suggest the first two(2) for example NBB_N10, NBB_N10, NBB_N10,..., CBB_N10 to be rows and the last two(2) for example AR0.8_RMSE, AR0.9_RMSE, AR0.95_RMSE,..., AR0.95_RMSE to be columns

Comment: You can split by `m1[,1]` or `m1[,2]` and then change the names with `m1[,2]`

Comment: Please check the first element of `str1 <- c("NBB_AR0.8", "NBB_N10_AR0.8_RMSE", "NBB_N10_AR0.9_RMSE", "NBB_N10_AR0.95_RMSE",  "MBB1_N10_AR0.8_RMSE", "MBB1_N10_AR0.9_RMSE", "MBB1_N10_AR0.95_RMSE",  "MBB2_N10_AR0.8_RMSE", "MBB2_N10_AR0.9_RMSE", "MBB2_N10_AR0.95_RMSE",  "MBB3_N10_AR0.8_RMSE", "MBB3_N10_AR0.9_RMSE", "MBB3_N10_AR0.95_RMSE",  "CBB_N10_AR0.8_RMSE", "CBB_N10_AR0.9_RMSE", "CBB_N10_AR0.95_RMSE" )` which is `"NBB_AR0.8"` is it suppose to be included or it is a mistake?

Comment: @DanielJames I was just checking different patterns and that is all.  You can remove it

Comment: I am able to follow up your instruction up to here `m1 <- do.call(rbind, strsplit(str1, "_(?=[A-Z0-9]+\\.)", perl = TRUE));m1[,1];m1[,2] ` after that I get lost. Please find me out.

Comment: @DanielJames The `m1` is a matrix which contains two columns whch corresponds to the two `sub` output we got here.  As we do the `split`, we use `m1[,1]` to split the original object

Comment: Yes, I got it as `matrix` as well; my next step has being to run `out1 <- future.apply::future_apply(str1[-1], 2, min)` which gives me error: `Error in future.apply::future_apply(str1[-1], 2, min) : 
  dim(X) must have a positive length`. That is where I size to find myself.

Comment: @DanielJames this is how I meant `m1 <- do.call(rbind, strsplit(names(df)[-1], "_(?=[A-Z0-9]+\\.)", perl = TRUE));  out1 <- future.apply::future_apply(df[-1], 2, min);lst1 <- split(setNames(out1, m1[,1]),  m1[,2]);do.call(rbind, lapply(lst1, function(x) x[!duplicated(x)]))`

Comment: @DanielJames your mistake in the code is that the future_apply was applied on the column names i.e. `str1` instead of the dataset

Comment: I have 3 by 4 matrix when I run `lst1 <- split(setNames(out1, m1[,1]),  m1[,2]);do.call(rbind, lapply(lst1, function(x) x[!duplicated(x)]))`. The columns are `NBB_N10,  MBB1_N10 , MBB3_N10, CBB_N10` while the rows are `AR0.8_RMSE, AR0.9_RMSE, AR0.95_RMSE` I think `MBB2_N10` is omitted and that the result is transposed from from your original solution as row is juxtaposed for column.

Comment: @DanielJames You may use `m1[,2]` instead of `m1[,1]` for split or just transpose by `t`

Answer (score 2):

A `tidyverse` solution could be

```r
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  pivot_longer(-c(lb), names_to = c("name", "name2"), names_pattern = "(.*)_(.*)") %>% 
  select(-lb) %>% 
  group_by(name, name2) %>% 
  slice_min(value) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = name2) %>% 
  ungroup()
```

returning

```r
# A tibble: 5 x 4
  name  AR0.8 AR0.9 AR0.95
  <chr> <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>
1 CBB   0.962 0.152 0.0838
2 MBB1  1.20  0.735 0.904 
3 MBB2  1.20  0.735 0.904 
4 MBB3  1.16  0.661 0.861 
5 NBB   0.937 0.444 0.517
```